# How to gather series of columns with data into rows

Tags: r

I'm just trying to get my head around tidying my data and I have this problem:

I have data as follows:

```
ID  Tx1  Tx1Date   Tx1Details Tx2  Tx2Date   Tx2Details Tx3  Tx1Date   Tx1Details  
1   14   12/3/14      blabla  1e   12/5/14   morebla   r    14/2/14   grrr
2   23   14/5/16      albalb  342  1/4/5     teeee     s    5/6/17    purrr
```

I want the data to be in the format

```
ID Tx  TxDate  TxDetails
1 14   12/3/14   blabla
1 1e   12/5/14   morebla
1 r    14/2/14   grrr
2 23   14/5/16   albalb 
2 342  1/4/5     teeee
2 s    5/6/17    purrr
```

I have used

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
NewData<-mydata %>% gather(key, value, "ID", 2:10)
```

but I'm not sure how to rename the columns as per the intended output to see if this will work

Comment: How in Satan's name did you get column names `Tx2Details` and `Tx1Date` to repeat in your data?

Comment: Do you mind providing the output of `structure(mydata)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data.table package handles this pretty well.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
melt(df, measure = list(Tx = grep("^Tx[0-3]$", names(df)), 
                        Date =  grep("Date", names(df)), 
                        Details = grep("Details", names(df))),
         value.name = c("Tx", "TxDate", "TxDetails"))
```

Or more concisely

```
melt(df, measure = patterns("^Tx[0-3]$", "Date", "Details"),
         value.name = c("Tx", "TxDate", "TxDetails"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rename your data frame column names to a more conventional separable names and then use the base `reshape` function, assuming your initial data frames looks like this(changed the last two column names to *Tx3Date* and *Tx3Details* as otherwise they are duplicates of columns 4 and 5):

```
df
#  ID Tx1 Tx1Date Tx1Details Tx2 Tx2Date Tx2Details Tx3 Tx3Date Tx3Details
#1  1  14 12/3/14     blabla  1e 12/5/14    morebla   r 14/2/14       grrr
#2  2  23 14/5/16     albalb 342   1/4/5      teeee   s  5/6/17      purrr

names(df) <- gsub("(\\d)(\\w*)", "\\2\\.\\1", names(df))

df
#  ID Tx.1 TxDate.1 TxDetails.1 Tx.2 TxDate.2 TxDetails.2 Tx.3 TxDate.3 TxDetails.3
#1  1   14  12/3/14      blabla   1e  12/5/14     morebla    r  14/2/14        grrr
#2  2   23  14/5/16      albalb  342    1/4/5       teeee    s   5/6/17       purrr

reshape(df, varying = 2:10, idvar = "ID", dir = "long")

#    ID time  Tx  TxDate TxDetails
#1.1  1    1  14 12/3/14    blabla
#2.1  2    1  23 14/5/16    albalb
#1.2  1    2  1e 12/5/14   morebla
#2.2  2    2 342   1/4/5     teeee
#1.3  1    3   r 14/2/14      grrr
#2.3  2    3   s  5/6/17     purrr
```

Drop the redundant `time` variable if you don't need it.

Comment: great code !! I had been waiting for an answer... sometimes I get confused between `dcast`, `gather`, `melt`,`reshape`. after seeing the answers, things look so easy but!